# Laravel db:table() returns empty set

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I am new to PHP and Laravel. I am following LaraCast tutorial and it creates a simple users table. The route function then gets all the users and returns to the browser. I can see data in the in db, but the result is always empty through Laravel route. Do I need to restart anything after creating the db, table ,etc? Thanks for your help.

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();

    return $users;
});
```

Database.php

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
            'database'  => 'awesomeproject',
            'username'  => 'homestead',
            'password'  => '***',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

When I hit http://awesome.app:8000/ I get [] as response.

mysql

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| awesomeproject     |
| homestead          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use awesomeproject
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
+--------------------------+
| Tables_in_awesomeproject |
+--------------------------+
| users                    |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
+----------+---------------+
| username | password      |
+----------+---------------+
| ulidder  | skjdfsjkhsdfs |
| user2    | dslfjasdfhw   |
+----------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes. I used Homestead with vagrant to set up my environment as I wanted to get started quickly. Just to check, I also used "root" as username and it also returns an empty set. Any way to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is `debug` set to `true` in `config/local/app.php`?
2. Make sure you are checking the connection credentials in `app/config/local/database.php`, not `app/config/database.php`. If you are using Homestead, your `app/config/local/database.php` should look something like this:

   ```
   'mysql' => array(
       'driver'    => 'mysql',
       'host'      => 'localhost',
       'database'  => 'homestead',
       'username'  => 'homestead',
       'password'  => 'secret',
       'charset'   => 'utf8',
       'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
       'prefix'    => '',
   ),
   ```

If you didn't set the credentials in `app/config/local/database.php`, you might be pulling results from the `homestead` database when you think you're querying the `awesomeproject` database.

Comment: Editing the local copy of database.php fixed the error. The course I am following does not use homestead and they configured app/config/database.php. The homestead database also happens to have an empty users table :(. Thank you for answering !